# Determining the probability of the count of Heads and Tails in a trial of 50 flips.

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to determine the probability of how many heads or tails show up after flipping a coin 50 times. If I wanted to determine the probability of getting 20 heads in 50 flips. How would I go about doing this? I do know that if I wanted to determine the probability of getting at least 1 head would be x = 1 - (0.5^L) where L is the number of total flips. I also know that if I wanted to determine the number of Heads when there were no tails flipped that the equation would be x = 0.5^L. For my question would the probability of getting 20 heads out of 50 coin tosses be x = 20 - (0.5^L)? Or am I not thinking about this the right way?

Comment: Your $20-0.5^L$ cannot be a probability as it exceeds $1$, so you are indeed thinking about this the wrong way.  You can either calculate the probability of $20$ from $50$  using combinatorics (how many equally probable ways of $20$ from $50$? how many equally probable ways in total?) or from the binomial distribution

Answer (score 1):

This is the [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), with $n = 50$ and $p = 0.5$. For a $B(n, p)$ distribution, the probability of getting $k$ "successes" (in this case, heads) is equal to the product of the probabilities of $k$ individual successes (which are all equal to $p$) and $n-k$ failures (which are all equal to $1-p$), multiplied by the number of ways to arrange them in different orders (e.g. for three coins and two heads, there's HHT, HTH and THH), which is equal to ${n \choose k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.

In other words:

$P(k \mbox{ successes}) = p^k (1-p)^{n-k} \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

so for your case, with $n=50, p=0.5, k=20$, that probability is:

$P(\mbox{20 heads}) = 0.5^{20} \times 0.5^{30} \frac{50!}{20!30!} \approx 0.0419$ (according to an [online calculator](https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx))

Note that if you're wondering how "unusual" it is to only get 20 heads out of 50 flips, you generally look at the probability of getting a result *at least as unusual*, which means we actually want the cumulative probability $P(\mbox{20 or fewer heads}) = P(k \leq 20) \approx 0.1013$

That is, you would get 20 heads about 1 in every 24 tries, but you would get 20 or fewer heads about 1 in every 10.